# Find determinant using lower triangular matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, triangularization

I have a matrix 4x4 :

\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 2 & 8 \\
-1 & 0 & -2 & 4 \\
4 & 2 & 8 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}

then I want to find determinan using lower triangular,which is the pattern of lower triangular :

\begin{matrix}
l11 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
l21 & l22 & 0 & 0 \\
l31 & l32 & l33 & 0 \\
l41 & l42 & l43 & l44
\end{matrix}

here my steps that I was try :

**Step 1 :**
change 8,4,2 to 0

\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 2 & \color{blue} 8 \\
-1 & 0 & -2 & \color{blue} 4 \\
4 & 2 & 8 & \color{blue} 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}

by :

**-4** x Row 4+Row 1

**-2** x Row 4+Row 2

**-1** x Row 4+Row 3

Result 1 :

\begin{matrix}
-6 & -7 & -6 & \color{purple} 0 \\
-5 & -4 & -6 & \color{purple} 0 \\
2 & 0 & 6 & \color{purple} 0 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}

**Step 2** : change -6,-6 to 0

\begin{matrix}
-6 & -7 & \color{blue}-\color{blue}6 & 0 \\
-5 & -4 & \color{blue}-\color{blue}6 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}

By :

**1x** Row 3 + Row 1

**1x** Row 3 + Row 2

Result 2 :

\begin{matrix}
-4 & -7 & \color{purple}0 & 0 \\
-3 & -4 & \color{purple}0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}

**Step 3** : change -7 to 0

\begin{matrix}
-6 & \color{blue}-\color{blue}7 & 0 & 0 \\
-3 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}

By :

$\frac{-7}{4}$ x Row 2 + Row 1

Result 3 :

\begin{matrix}
1 \frac{1}{4} & \color{purple}0 & 0 & 0 \\
-3 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}

and then I multiplies the diagonal :

\begin{matrix}
\color{red}1\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-3 & \color{red}-\color{red}4 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & \color{red}6 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & \color{red}2
\end{matrix}

1 $\frac{1}{4}$ x -3 x 6 x 2 = 240

Why I get **240** ? it's should **-60**

Anyone can correct my matrix or steps ?

Comment: `\begin{vmatrix}…\end{vmatrix}` produces delimiters for determinants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the last step is wrong. What is?

$$1.25\cdot\left(-4\right)\cdot6\cdot2$$

And $-6$ in the beginning of step 3 should've been $-4$ but that doesn't matter, you didn't carry this error to the result of the step.

Comment: how u get 1.25 ?

Comment: $$1\frac{1}4=1.25$$ @RobyFirnandoYusuf

Comment: OOOH .... I see ... thank you u save me ^_^

Comment: You're welcome :)